# Change active li when clicking link

Tags: html, css

I currently have a list in my navigation:

```
<ul class="nav menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="main.php"> MainPage</a></li>
    <li><a href="hello.php"> Second Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="third.php"> Third Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="/knowledgebase/"> Knowledge Base</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like the active class to change when a link has been clicked. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: And link goes to another page/reloads page? Since you use php, easiest way is to separate menu in e.g. menu.php file (which will be used as a a part of template/included in page template), check current page, and add appropriate class to active link....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735317/jquery-navigation)

Comment: @CommercialSuicide the OP did not mention that he wants to use [tag:jquery] nor if he is looking for a javascript solution.

Comment: @Incompetent: Are you looking for a css only solution? Are you willing to use a clientside (javascript) or serverside (php) solution? If i am on page third.php should the class `active` be set for this listitem if i know click on hello.php then a new page would be loaded (at least that is what i assume based on the infos i have)? Now that i am on hello.php the active class should be set on the second listitem?

Comment: @surfmuggle, OK, my fault

Comment: It doesn't have to be a css only solution but yes, if you are on third.php then the class active should be set for this listitem

Comment: @Incompetent, you will have to provide some context... Are pages 'static', or 'dynamic' (complete content loaded from database, or something similar), is menu part of every page, or is it separated, and should be dinamically loaded to page template, etc, etc...

Comment: If you have the server side under your control i would go with a server side solution (php): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303885/

Answer (score 0):

Remove active class from all li and add it to the current clicked li

```js
$("li").click(
    function(event) {
      $('li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      event.preventDefault()
    }
);
```

```css
.active a{
color:red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="main.php"> MainPage</a></li>
    <li><a href="hello.php"> Second Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="third.php"> Third Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="/knowledgebase/"> Knowledge Base</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Since OP did not mention how clicks on `<a href=....>` are handled your suggestion might not work. As soon as a user clicks on a link the browser leaves the current page and loads the new page. Even if your javascript still fires it won't be relevant on the newly loaded page: https://plnkr.co/edit/BjF9gST3o29uj28epReJ?p=preview

Comment: This might still not work. You have to take [event bubbling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/) into consideration. In [this demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/o2sqkwUH2UGh0b4ItpRr?p=preview) i added some additional information

Answer (score 0):

I understood the following if the user clicks on a link the class of the parent node should be set to active

```
<ul class="nav menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="main.php">Main Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="hello.php">hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### Option 1: Server side solution

If a user clicks on a link `<a href="...">link</a>` the browser navigates to this link. Based on the links in your code this would mean that the browser leaves the page `main.php` and loads `hello.php`. In this case your server receives the  request for the page and returns the page to the client (the browser). Since your link contains `.php` i assume that you use php for [server side rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35668884/819887). To [add your navigation menu to every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428585/include-menu-on-every-page) you could us `include('myMenu.php');`

This [answer explains how include works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905273/819887). Now you could write the following inside hello.php

```
<?php
    $hello = 'active';
    include 'myMenu.php';
?>
```

And `myMenu.php` could look like this

```
<ul class="nav menu">
    <li class="<?php echo $main; ?>"><a href="main.php">Main Page</a></li>
    <li class="<?php echo $hello;?>"><a href="hello.php">hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have no php installed and could not test it but [i created this codepad demo](http://codepad.org/xznRCFhl) and the output is this

```
<ul class="nav menu">
    <li class=""><a href="main.php">Main Page</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="hello.php">hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

Since inside `hello.php` the variable `$hello` was set to active and the variable `$main` was not defined the output is `class="active"` for `$hello` and  `class=""` for `$main`.

#### Option 2: Client side solution

A client side solution using javascript.

- make sure that you [prevent `any default action normally taken by the implementation`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-preventDefault). `The default behavior associated with a link is the retrieval of another Web resource` this means the browser navigates to the next page (see [HTML 4.01 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.1.1)). So clicking on a link `<a href="hello.php">hello<php>` must not fire the default behaviour.
- load the matching content (the content of page `hello.php` into the current page. This is done by an javascript ajax request (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429543/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081676/)).
- set the active class for the parent node (your list item `<li>`

A few pointers

- [Document Object Model (DOM) Level 2 Events Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow): The event is dispatched to its target EventTarget and any event listeners found there are triggered. Bubbling events will then trigger any additional event listeners found by following the EventTarget's parent chain upward,
- Capturing: Event capture is the process by which an EventListener registered on an ancestor of the event's target can intercept events of a given type before they are received by the event's target. Capture operates from the top of the tree, generally the Document, downward, making it the symmetrical opposite of bubbling which is described below. The chain of EventTargets from the top of the tree to the event's target is determined before the initial dispatch of the event.
- Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/819887) `IE < 9 uses only event bubbling, whereas IE9+ and all major browsers support both`

If you want it to work in IE<9 you have to prevent the default behaviour for a click on the link `<a ...` and not the parent node `<li ...>`. The other answers do not take this into consideration.

#### Conclusion

Without more information which option you are looking for this is fishing in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

HTML :

```
<ul class="nav menu">
    <li><a href="main.php"> MainPage</a></li>
    <li><a href="hello.php"> Second Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="third.php"> Third Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="/knowledgebase/"> Knowledge Base</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript :

```
$(function() {
    var u = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
                .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $(".nav li a").each(function() {
    $h = $(this).attr("href");
    if ($h == u || $h == '')
        $(this).addClass("active");
    })
});
```

**Be sure to add jQuery!**

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in multiple ways depending on the frontend framework you are using. You can use Jquery to detect clicks and add/remove classes.

```
$("li").click(
    function(event) {
      $('li').removeClass('active')
      $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('active')
    }
);
```

What this is doing is checking for clicks on all `li` elements. Once there is a click it removes the `active` class from all `li` elements and adds `active` class to the currently clicked element. Here is the plunkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/E6wIUgzkvNjn0xFQoa7F?p=preview

Comment: As it currently looks if the user clicks on a link `<a href=hello.php>` this click will not be intercepted.  The page hello.php will be loaded. I forked your plunk to show what i mean: https://plnkr.co/edit/BjF9gST3o29uj28epReJ?p=preview

Comment: Yes. He can use a separate `nav menu` for each of the pages I guess with the `active` class appropriately changed.